# How create an EXI file out of an XML and several XSD files?

Tags: xml, xsd, exi, exificient

I am using [EXIficient](https://sourceforge.net/projects/exificient/) to convert XML data to EXI.
It works great for an XML and an XSD pair, but does not works when I try to use a XSD composed of 2 others XSDs (`<xs:import namespace=...`), which are themselves composed of others XSDs.

Can I flatten these XSDs manually ? (XSDs newbie here, I read that with `<xs:import...` flatten application do not work.)

If someone know EXIficient, is it possible to use multiples XSDs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try having one XSD file "root" that import all XSDs (so no nested XSD).
And give that XSD file to EXIficient.

Comment: There is a "root" file, which import two XSDs who themselves import a XSDs. `<xs:import namespace="_______" schemaLocation="___"/>`... or am I confusing ?

Comment: you need only 1 file that does all the import (and no other files doing import), I've read something about that solution.

Comment: But does this work with Exificient. I seem to be getting an error all the time that it can't find the referenced schema. I wonder if it has to do anything with the import? The referenced schema is placed in the same directory as the one being used.